# Doubt in zeroes of Klein J Function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-function

While studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory I am unable to think about a conclusion of theorem 2.7 .

It's image - [image]

> I have doubt in how there is a triple zero at $\rho$ and J($\tau$) -1 has a double zero at $\tau$ = i.
>
> Apostol writes that it's a consequence of Theorem 2.4 which is If f is modular and not identically zero, then in closure of fundamental region $R_\Gamma$ , number of zeroes of f equal to number of poles.

Can someone please explain how to derive this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\,D(\tau) = E_4(\tau)^3-E_6(\tau)^2,\,$ then
$\, J(\tau) = E_4(\tau)^3/D(\tau)\,$ where
$\,E_4\,$ and $\,E_6\,$ are
[Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).
At the value $\,\rho=(1+\sqrt{-3})/2\,$ we have $\,E_4(\rho)=0\,$ and
$\,E_6(\rho)\ne 0.\,$ Thus $\,J(\tau)\,$ has a triple zero at $\,\rho.\,$
At the value $\,i=\sqrt{-1}\,$ we have $\,E_4(i) \ne 0\,$ and
$\,E_6(i) = 0.\,$
Since $\,J(\tau)-1 = E_6(\tau)^2/D(\tau)\,$ the function
$\,J(\tau)-1\,$ has a double zero at $\,i.\,$

Note that $\,D(\tau)=2^{12}\,\eta(\tau)^{24}\,$ and $\,\eta\,$ is nonzero in $H$. Thus  $D$ is nonzero in $H$ and therefore not both
$\,E_4\,$ and $\,E_6\,$ are zero.

Note that $$E_4(\tau) = (\eta(\tau)^{24} +
256\,\eta(2\tau)^{24})/(\eta(\tau)\eta(2\tau))^8$$
whose numerator splits into distinct linear factors
one of which is $\,\eta(\tau)^8 - 2^{8/3}(1-\rho)\,
\eta(2\tau)^8\,$ which is zero if $\,\tau=\rho\,$ and
this is why $\,E_4\,$ has a simple zero at $\,\rho.$

Note that $$E_6(\tau) \!=\!(\eta(\tau)^{16} \!-\!
 512\,\eta(\tau)^8\tau(4\tau)^8 \!-\! 8192\,\eta(4\tau)^{16})\\
(\eta(\tau)^8 \!+\!
 32\,\eta(4\tau)^8) / \eta(2\tau)^{12} $$
whose numerator splits into distinct linear factors
one of which is
$\,\eta(\tau)^8 \!-\! 2^6(4\!+\!\sqrt{18})\,
\eta(4\tau)^8\,$ which is zero if $\,\tau=i\,$ and
this is why $\,E_6\,$ has a simple zero at $\,i.$

---

Note that the Wikipedia [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#Special_values)
article Special values section lists the values

> $$\eta(i) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{2^{\frac78}\pi^{\frac34}}$$
> $$\eta(2i) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac14)}{2^{\frac{11}8}\pi^{\frac34}}$$

Using these values, verify that
$\,E_4(i) = \frac3{64}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)^8}{\pi^6} \approx 1.4557 \ne 0$ and
similarly for $\,E_6(\rho).$

Comment: only doubt I have is how to prove that $E_6(\rho) \neq 0 $ and $E_4(i) \neq 0 $. Can you please prove that!!

Answer (score 0):

- $J-a$ has only one simple pole on the modular curve (which is a compact Riemann surface) thus it has only one simple zero.
- $J(i)$ is the $J$-invariant of (the isomorphism class of) the complex torus $\Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z})$, the only one with complex multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. The Weierstrass function gives an isomorphism to an elliptic curve $E:y^2=4x^3+Ax+B$. Since the elliptic curve $E':y^2=x^3-ax-a,(a,b)=(1,0)$ has complex multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ (sending $(x,y) \to (-x,iy)$) it means $E\cong E'$ and hence $J(i)=J(E)=J(E')=\frac{4a^3}{4a^3+27b^2} =1$.
- For $J(e^{2i\pi /3})=0$ it is the same with $\Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z}+e^{2i\pi/3}\Bbb{Z})$ and $y^2=x^3-1$ having CM by $\Bbb{Z}[e^{2i\pi/3}]$ (sending $(x,y)\to (e^{2i\pi /3}x,y)$)
- The chart from a small disk $|z|<\epsilon$ to $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i$ is not $z\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})(i+z)$ but $z\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z})ie^{z^{1/2}}$, this is because $i$ is fixed by $\tau\to -1/\tau$, thus $J-1$ has a simple zero at $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i$ means that $J(z)-1$ has a double zero at $i$.
- There are 3 elements of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ fixing $e^{2i\pi /3}$ thus $J$ has a simple zero at  $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})e^{2i\pi /3}$ means that $J(z)$ has a triple zero at $e^{2i\pi /3}$.

Comment: I am sorry but i haven't studied elliptic curves or torus. Isn't there an explanation  that avoids these ?

Comment: an explanation of what

Comment: explanation of the question asked by me!! Also Apostol in both volumes never mentioned elliptic curves or torus

Comment: ... I only use it to find the value of $J(i),J(e^{2i\pi /3})$... Who said you had to work only with Apostol's book.